# beautifulsoup4 nested navigation issues

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am using BS4 to scrape a website with data definitions and have run into a few issues. I was able to get 3 out of 7-8 different fields. Here is an example of the data I am trying to grab:

```
 <div class="MCDropDown MCDropDown_Closed dropDown"><span class="MCDropDownHead dropDownHead"><a aria-expanded="false" class="MCDropDownHotSpot dropDownHotspot MCDropDownHotSpot_" href="#"></a><a name="WorkingTime"></a><a aria-expanded="false" class="MCDropDownHotSpot dropDownHotspot MCDropDownHotSpot_ MCHotSpotImage" href="#"><p class="card-title">Working Time (WT) 
                 </p><p>The amount of time an agent was available or actively handling contacts.</p><img alt="Closed" class="MCDropDown_Image_Icon" data-mc-alt2="Open" height="12" src="../../../Skins/Default/Stylesheets/Images/transparent.gif" width="16"/></a></span>
 <div class="MCDropDownBody dropDownBody">
 <div class="card-heading">Available In</div>
 <p><a href="../customreporting/customreporting.htm">Custom reporting</a>, <a href="../directdataaccess/directdataaccessoverview.htm">DDA</a></p>
 <div class="card-heading">Calculation</div>
 <p>[<a href="#AvailableTime">Available Time</a>] + [<a href="#InboundTime">Inbound Time</a>] + [<a href="#OutboundTime">Outbound Time</a>] + [<a href="#ACWTime">ACW Time</a>] + [<a href="#ConsultTime">Consult Time</a>]</p>
 <div class="card-heading">Source</div>
 <p>ACD, Personal Connection</p>
 <div class="card-heading">Paradigm</div>
 <p>Contact start, true to interval</p>
 <div class="card-heading">Model</div>
 <p>Contact detail, contact summary, intraday</p>
 <div class="card-heading">Perspective</div>
 <p>Agent, PC</p>
 <div class="card-heading">Metric Type</div>
 <p>Time</p>
 <div class="card-heading">Format</div>
 <p>##.##</p>
 </div>
 </div>]
```

The main problem I am having is that the data does not always appear in the same order (Sometimes 'paradigm' is third, sometimes its 'calcaulation'). My question, is how can I navigate to 'Source'  (or any other title) after using the following code to get the data, or how can I make sure when I am creating lists to fill a data frame only the 'Source' data fills the 'Source' list, etc.

```
for div in soup2:

    print(div.find_all(['div', 'p']))
```

```
[<div class="card-heading">Available In</div>, <p><a href="../customreporting/customreporting.htm">Custom reporting</a>, <a href="../directdataaccess/directdataaccessoverview.htm">DDA</a></p>, <div class="card-heading">Source</div>, <p>ACD, Personal Connection</p>, <div class="card-heading">Paradigm</div>, <p>Contact start, true to interval</p>, <div class="card-heading">Model</div>, <p>Contact detail, contact summary, PC list management, intraday</p>, <div class="card-heading">Perspective</div>, <p>Agent, contact, PC</p>]
[<div class="card-heading">Available In</div>, <p><a href="../customreporting/customreporting.htm">Custom reporting</a>, <a href="../directdataaccess/directdataaccessoverview.htm">DDA</a></p>, <div class="card-heading">Source</div>, <p>ACD, Personal Connection</p>, <div class="card-heading">Paradigm</div>, <p>Contact start, true to interval</p>, <div class="card-heading">Model</div>, <p>Contact detail, contact summary, PC list management, intraday</p>, <div class="card-heading">Perspective</div>, <p>Agent, contact, PC</p>]
[<div class="card-heading">Available In</div>, <p><a href="../prebuiltreports/agentsnapshotreport.htm">Agent snapshot</a>, <a href="../customreporting/customreporting.htm">custom reporting</a>, <a href="../directdataaccess/directdataaccessoverview.htm">DDA</a>, <a href="../prebuiltreports/supervisorsnapshotreport.htm">supervisor snapshot</a></p>, <div class="card-heading">Source</div>, <p>ACD, Personal Connection</p>, <div class="card-heading">Paradigm</div>, <p>Contact start, true to interval</p>, <div class="card-heading">Model</div>, <p>Contact detail, contact summary, PC list management, intraday</p>, <div class="card-heading">Perspective</div>, <p>Agent, contact, PC</p>]
[<div class="card-heading">Available In</div>, <p><a href="../directdataaccess/directdataaccessoverview.htm">DDA</a>
```

Desired logic

```
source_text_list = []
paradigm_list = []
etc...

for rows in soup:

     try:

          source_text_list.append(soup.find_all('Source').text)

     except IndexError:

           source_text_list.append('')

     try:

          paradigm_list.append(soup.find_all('Paradigm').text)

     except IndexError:

           paradigm_list.append('')
```

etc until all possible fields are filled for each entry

There are also some entries where data exists on multiple lines:

```
<div class="card-heading">Calculation</div>
 <p>Count of unique CONTACT_IDs where:</p>
 <ul>
 <li>Agent State = LOGGEDIN, LOGGEDOUT</li>
 </ul>
 <p>OR</p>
 <ul>
 <li>Outstate = TRUE AND NOT = HELDPARTABANDON, REFUSED</li>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Pretty hard to get the whole picture, but assuming there are several dropdowns you can iterate each of them and extract the information of `<div>` with class `card-heading` and its next `<p>`:

###### Example

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html='''
<div class="MCDropDown MCDropDown_Closed dropDown"><span class="MCDropDownHead dropDownHead"><a aria-expanded="false" class="MCDropDownHotSpot dropDownHotspot MCDropDownHotSpot_" href="#"></a><a name="WorkingTime"></a><a aria-expanded="false" class="MCDropDownHotSpot dropDownHotspot MCDropDownHotSpot_ MCHotSpotImage" href="#"><p class="card-title">Working Time (WT) 
                 </p><p>The amount of time an agent was available or actively handling contacts.</p><img alt="Closed" class="MCDropDown_Image_Icon" data-mc-alt2="Open" height="12" src="../../../Skins/Default/Stylesheets/Images/transparent.gif" width="16"/></a></span>
 <div class="MCDropDownBody dropDownBody">
 <div class="card-heading">Available In</div>
 <p><a href="../customreporting/customreporting.htm">Custom reporting</a>, <a href="../directdataaccess/directdataaccessoverview.htm">DDA</a></p>
 <div class="card-heading">Calculation</div>
 <p>[<a href="#AvailableTime">Available Time</a>] + [<a href="#InboundTime">Inbound Time</a>] + [<a href="#OutboundTime">Outbound Time</a>] + [<a href="#ACWTime">ACW Time</a>] + [<a href="#ConsultTime">Consult Time</a>]</p>
 <div class="card-heading">Source</div>
 <p>ACD, Personal Connection</p>
 <div class="card-heading">Paradigm</div>
 <p>Contact start, true to interval</p>
 <div class="card-heading">Model</div>
 <p>Contact detail, contact summary, intraday</p>
 <div class="card-heading">Perspective</div>
 <p>Agent, PC</p>
 <div class="card-heading">Metric Type</div>
 <p>Time</p>
 <div class="card-heading">Format</div>
 <p>##.##</p>
 </div>
 </div>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

data = []

for e in soup.select('div.MCDropDownBody'):
    data.append({e.text:e.find_next('p').text for e in soup.select('.card-heading')})
```

Output data:

```
[{'Available In': 'Custom reporting, DDA', 'Calculation': '[Available Time] + [Inbound Time] + [Outbound Time] + [ACW Time] + [Consult Time]', 'Source': 'ACD, Personal Connection', 'Paradigm': 'Contact start, true to interval', 'Model': 'Contact detail, contact summary, intraday', 'Perspective': 'Agent, PC', 'Metric Type': 'Time', 'Format': '##.##'}]
```

Or alternative as `DataFrame`:

```
pd.DataFrame(data)
```

| Available In | Calculation | Source | Paradigm | Model | Perspective | Metric Type | Format |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Custom reporting, DDA | [Available Time] + [Inbound Time] + [Outbound Time] + [ACW Time] + [Consult Time] | ACD, Personal Connection | Contact start, true to interval | Contact detail, contact summary, intraday | Agent, PC | Time | ##.## |

Comment: This is great! Thank you so much! I was able to concatenate the dataframe with the fields I already grabbed to complete the list! I did notice there were some weird instances where 'calculation' is on multiple lines:

`<div class="card-heading">Calculation</div>
 <p>Count of unique CONTACT_IDs where:</p>
 <ul>
 <li>Agent State = LOGGEDIN, LOGGEDOUT</li>
 </ul>
 <p>OR</p>
 <ul>
 <li>Outstate = TRUE AND NOT = HELDPARTABANDON, REFUSED</li>
 </ul>`

Is there any way to get all of it?

Comment: Happy to help - Cause there should be only one issue per question, this would be predestined to [ask a new one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with exact this focus. Mention it and we will take a closer look. Thanks